# Google Play - Internal Testing - Inactive

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-bundle

One of the developers by mistake **published** the app on Google Play before release. Then it was **unpublished** for safety reasons.

Then **internal testing** release was created, countries selected, testers added... (with .oob bundle).

Everyone got invites, we shared app links to testers, but the app doesn't show. Then we noticed, track summary - **inactive** status for internal testing.

What might make status active for internal testing? (publishing back the app is not an option, as **we don't want the app to be available for everybody**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hear me out**

**Option 1** (recommended)

- republish the app to production
- remove all `countries / regions` from production
- so now, the app will be on production but not available to anyone
- then you will see that the internal app is active again

**Option 2**
publish the app as a [private app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cregister-as-a-developer%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization) then make it public when you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing all countries was not an option for the app, but private app idea helped.

Comment: Also seems publishing triggered app review, so unless I publish manually after review (which was an option, and I used it) nobody can download it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remove all the countries, so another solution would be.

1. Go to coutries list and pick a country that you don't care.
2. Make your app published
3. Your internal testing track should be active now, and testers can continue doing internal testings, as they are not limited by countries.